# Android getMaxAddressLineIndex returns 0 for line 1

Tags: android, android-location

For some reason the implementation of getMaxAddressLineIndex has recently changed. Now this method returns 0 for line 1.

I have an existing code, which used to work:  `i<address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(`). However, it is broken somehow.

[image]

I don't know if it is due to the new Google Api or something else.

Can someone please confirm me here what is going on?

Comment: Brother, Do you found the solution? I got the same problem :(

Comment: @SarinSuriyakoon Only solution that I can come is start considering 0 as your first item and -1 means none!

Comment: look for that solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208116/geocoder-returns-an-address-with-zero-length

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same issue and this just a workaround.

```
if (address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
        addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
    }
} else {
    try {
        addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(0));
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Restating the answer below by **mdicosimo** 

The code is behaving correct and is returning the maximum index. It is not  the count of lines, rather the highest valid index.  


    `// Notice less-then-or-equal   <= not just less-than <
    for (int idx = 0; idx <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); idx++) {
          String line = address.getAddress(idx);
    }`

Answer (score 5):

The same happened to me.
I verified that Developer Reference (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getMaxAddressLineIndex()) now states:

**int getMaxAddressLineIndex ()**

**Returns the largest index currently in use to specify an address line. If no address lines are specified, -1 is returned.**

So it seems to reflect the new behaviour.

Anyway, to be safe, I'm going to enclose `getAddressLine(i)` inside `try\catch`

Comment: Appreciate this @mdicosimo - but Dear Google what has happened to api version control? It does not offer a good user experience if extant api behaviour changes with already released apps ...

Comment: in some mi phones it returns 0. although there are values for locality, sublocality etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think `getAddressLine()` has changed.  It used to return the various elements of the address in separate calls to `...getAddressLine(0)`, `...getAddressLine(1)` and so on up to `getAddressLine(n)` where `n` is `...getMaxAddressLineIndex()`.

Now it seems to return the entire address concatenated and comma-separated into the call to `...getAddressLine(0)`, and `...getMaxAddressLineIndex()` always returns zero (if an address is returned, or -1 if no address returned).

For example, in the old version, the `lat/long` of the Houses of Parliament in London would return (for the first address returned) 4 address lines:

```
addressLines=[0:"9748 Abingdon Street",1:"Westminster, London",2:"SW1P 3JY",3:"UK"]
```

Now it returns one line:

```
addressLines=[0:"9748 Abingdon St, Westminster, London SW1P 3JY, UK"]
```

That seems to be what happens to me.  I've tried it on a *Moto G5 Plus* with *Android 7* and a *Samsung* tablet with *Android 6*.  My Android emulators still work the old way.  Someone tell me if I've got that wrong!

Note: in the past you could test `i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex()` rather than `<=` .  This just meant you didn't get the last element, which always seemed to be the abreviated country name (e.g. "USA").  Now that `.getMaxAddressLineIndex()` always seems to return zero, that won't work.  But note you get "USA" appended to the string returned to `.getAddressLine(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

As user8533943 has pointed out above the implementation has been changed surreptitiously. However I am of the opinion that

> geocoder.getFromLocation()

has changed it's implementation. It returns a list of addresses and each address consists of address lines.
But as far as I could see when I compiled with version 26 of the SDK there aren't "address lines" being returned but just one line for every address.

So if you have just one address then

> getMaxAddressLineIndex()

would in fact return 0

Update your implementation as follows to use a **<=** comparison.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
```