# Geocoder returns an address with zero length

Tags: android, android-location

Geocoder was working fine until today. It started to return String with 0 length.
Note: This is not a duplicate of Geocoder threads, i used intent service and AsyncTask to get it before starting the thread(and AsyncTask approach was working fine over 8 months), checked [this code](http://www.androidauthority.com/get-location-address-android-app-628764/) and new [code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationAddress) from Google with FusedLocationProviderClient(this is offical code) it also returns string with zero length.[This link](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html) from official Android page shows how to get it with intent service.

I get full address on Android 5.1 but on Android 7.1 it returns an address with length zero.

Code i used to use and worked fine until today.

```
private void getAddressFromCoordinates() {

    new AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                addresses.clear();
                addresses.addAll(geocoder.getFromLocation(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),
                        mCurrentLocation.getLongitude(), 1));


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showToastAsync(getString(R.string.activity_loc_no_location_info));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
                // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
                showToastAsync("Invalid latitude or longitude values");
            }

            // Handle case where no address was found.
            if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
                showToastAsync(getString(R.string.activity_loc_no_address_is_found));
            } else {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                ArrayList<String> addressFragments = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
                }

                addressInfo = TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"), addressFragments);
                addressSingleLine = LocationActivity.addressInfo.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", " ");
            }
            return null;
        }

    }.execute();
}
```

**Answer** is to add `=` to for loop to not retreive an address with zero length on Android 7. You don't need to do this on some versions. Also code on Google referenced Github pages is missing **=**. That's why i was not able to find the reason why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is this line:

*for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)*

It must be : *for (int i = 0; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)*
Because getMaxAddressLineIndex returns the largest index.

Comment: Yes, = is what should be added but it works if Android version is not 7. It's very interesting. Can anyone explain why it works on if version is not Anroid 7?

Comment: Yeap that worked.  What a weird change in their API.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed the exact same issue in my code a while ago. Apparently this is a change in the API as you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getMaxAddressLineIndex()). Now `getMaxAddressLineIndex()`:

> Returns the largest index currently in use to specify an address line. If no address lines are specified, -1 is returned.

So you need to change the condition of your `for` loop as suggested by @DavidBar

Comment: Yes, i looked it today and adding `=` to foor loop is what was missing. Interesting thing is it works on Android 5 and 6 without equal sign. I really wonder why it does not work on some Android versions and work on others.